# Updating a field in a MySQL table if it's empty

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query in C#

```
REPLACE INTO users(uid, username, firstseen, ...)
VALUES(@uid, @username, @firstseen, ...)
```

I am looking to update the user record but I don't want to change firstseen apart from the first time I see this user. I could query the database but that would add alot of overhead is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: We need to see more context. What else does your code do? How do you define the first time you "see" the user?

Comment: What more context could you need?  This question is perfectly clear.

Comment: @Jamie...could you be more specific with the requirement "I don't want to change firstseen apart from the first time I see this user" I don't really understantd what that means.

Comment: It seems to me that what firstseen should only be updated if it is currently null and if there is a value in that column it should not be updated.

Comment: @Andomar - I hope you're being sarcastic.

Comment: Yeah. @JoeW is right, if firstseen is null then it should be updated but if it has a value then it should not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REPLACE INTO` will stomp any data already present and is equivalent to a `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT` statement.

What you might want is:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO users (uid, username, screenname, ...)
  VALUES (@...)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uid=VALUES(uid), username=VALUES(username), ...
```

You can assign specific fields in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` section as required, omitting those that are obviously the same.

Comment: +1 include `firstseen` in the `insert` and exclude it in the `on duplicate key`, probably shortest way to write this in MySQL :)